# Nesting APIs routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

Im trying to create API endpoints from my Post model . It should be able to read, update, delete and create posts.

But a post needs to be assosiated to a Topic in order for it to be created so i nested it under topics. Here are my routes

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update]
      resources :posts, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
      resources :topics, except: [:edit, :new] do
        resources :posts, only: [:create]
      end
    end
  end 

       api_v1_post GET    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                api/v1/posts#show
                   PATCH  /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                api/v1/posts#update
                   PUT    /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                api/v1/posts#update
                   DELETE /api/v1/posts/:id(.:format)                api/v1/posts#destroy
api_v1_topic_posts POST   /api/v1/topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)   api/v1/posts#create
     api_v1_topics GET    /api/v1/topics(.:format)                   api/v1/topics#index
                   POST   /api/v1/topics(.:format)                   api/v1/topics#create
      api_v1_topic GET    /api/v1/topics/:id(.:format)               api/v1/topics#show
                   PATCH  /api/v1/topics/:id(.:format)               api/v1/topics#update
                   PUT    /api/v1/topics/:id(.:format)               api/v1/topics#update
                   DELETE /api/v1/topics/:id(.:format)               api/v1/topics#destroy
```

my issue is  im getting a "no routes match" error when i run my Rspec

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I don't think nesting that is actually a good idea. Instead, I would simply have the topic be a parameter in the post data. If the topic is pre-determined in the `new` form, then you can have that value in a hidden input.

Comment: I'm nesting if cause I'm following instructions in a course I'm taking , I'm very new to APIs so I'm pretty much lost right now . "Create an endpoint for POST api/v1/topics/:topic_id/create_post. Because a post must be associated with a topic, nest this endpoint under topics in routes and add the action to 'Api::V1::TopicsController.'" This is what I was instructed to do

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct route mappings? I expect to see something like: `POST /api/v1/topics/:id/post` for the post path with the nesting up there. try to check that again... run rake routes and show the result. What rails version are you using? Rails 4?

Comment: sorry i forgot to post "api_v1_topic_posts POST   /api/v1/topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)   api/v1/posts#create
" its there

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the relationship.

Please add the relationship between `Topic` and `Post` and then try.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :topic
end
```

Comment: the assosiation has already been implemented for both topics and posts

Answer (score 0):

If the route you are trying to create is `POST api/v1/topics/:topic_id/create_post` going to TopicsController than you would want the nesting to look like this instead:

```
resources :topics, except: [:edit, :new] do
  post 'create_post' => 'topics#create_post'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for creating your routes if you haven't had success yet. It should provide the output that you want.

```
resources :topics, except: [:edit, :new] do
   collection do
      post 'create_post'
   end
end
```